# Android need to share Image and text together all social medias

Tags: android

need to share Image and text together all social medias I used this it only share the image on facebook

```
//              Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
//              Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.hunter99x/" + R.drawable.ninexgreen);
//              Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path.toString());
//              sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
//              sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body text of the new status");
//              sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
//              startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Please take some time to edit it to be more specific and clear.

Comment: The code you are using is correct. It will bring up a list with all installed apps that allow sharing images. If the apps you want to use are not listed then they probably don't allow sharing images.

Comment: The guy wants to share an Image AND Text, not just an image. Question is actually pretty clear to me. Title says Image and Text together. Description indicates only image was shared.

Comment: @Fraggle can u please help me i am also facing same problem to achieve this target

Comment: @Friend have u  achieved your target i am also facing same